# How can I use the `with` statement with `call.apoc.do.when` in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Firstly, you can create sample nodes with following commands,

```
CREATE (t1:Title { tid: '123abc'})
CREATE (t2:Title { tid: '123def'})
CREATE (t3:Title { tid: '123456'})
CREATE (t4:Title { tid: '123789'})
CREATE (u:User { pid: '456def'})

CREATE (t1)-[r:TO]->(t2)
CREATE (t2)-[r:TO]->(t3)
CREATE (t3)-[r:TO]->(t4)
CREATE (u)-[r:LIKE]->(t3)
```

Here is the graph,

[image: graph]

I have a query like that in Neo4j,

```
MATCH (t1:Title)-[r:TO]->(t2:Title)
WHERE t1.tid = '123abc'
AND NOT exists((t2)<-[:LIKE|:DISLIKE|:LOVE]-(:User {pid: '456def'}))
WITH COLLECT(r) AS rels
LIMIT 1

WITH rels
CALL apoc.do.when(
    SIZE(rels) > 0,
    'RETURN REDUCE(total = 0, x IN rels | total + x.weight) AS result',
    'RETURN 0 AS result'
) YIELD value
RETURN value.result
```

I want to use `rels` variable in `do.when` blog. There is a no problem for `SIZE(rels) > 0` expression, but in `if statement` returns error like that,

> > Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.do.when`: Caused by: org.neo4j.exceptions.SyntaxException: Variable `rels` not defined (line 1, column 31 (offset: 30))
> > "RETURN REDUCE(total = 0, x IN rels | total + x.weight) AS result"

I'm newbie in Neo4j. I think, there is a special case for `REDUCE`. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/cypher-execution/conditionals/), you can add a third parameter that includes parameters for inners statements:

```
MATCH (t1:Title)-[r:TO]->(t2:Title)
WHERE t1.tid = '123abc'
AND NOT exists((t2)<-[:LIKE|:DISLIKE|:LOVE]-(:User {pid: '456def'}))
WITH COLLECT(r) AS rels
LIMIT 1

WITH rels
CALL apoc.do.when(
    SIZE(rels) > 0,
    'RETURN REDUCE(total = 0, x IN rels | total + x.weight) AS result',
    'RETURN 0 AS result',
    {rels:rels}
) YIELD value
RETURN value.result
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have an another question. Is there a random number generator between specific numbers in Neo4j? Afaik, `rand()` function generates number between [0, 1).

Comment: You can use linear transformation... e.g numbers between 0 to 10 is rand() * 10... 5 to 15 is (rand() * 10) + 5... another way would be to create a list of possible numbers and use apoc.coll.randomItem(coll)

Answer (score 2):

The sum can be directly obtained using the [aggregation function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `SUM`:

```
MATCH (t1:Title)-[r:TO]->(t2:Title)
WHERE t1.tid = '123abc' AND NOT EXISTS((t2)<-[:LIKE|:DISLIKE|:LOVE]-(:User {pid: '456def'}))
RETURN SUM(r.weight) AS result
```

Comment: That's a quick solution, thanks. But actually, my primary problem is how can I use a variable in `do.when`. Real query what I work on is more complex.